# Is twilio a good choice for implementing this scenario

Tags: twilio

So basicaly, we already have a website that allows users to be in the same room to visualize schemas, interact with it, chat about it, all under the control of an admin of the room that monitors what other users see.

We are looking to add an audio conferencing feature, and I'm currently doing a technological watch on which Real Time Communication solution would be the best to fill our needs.

Our problematic is simple.
The admin would have a button "start a conference" to create a room.
When the room's created the other users would see a message like "The admin launched an audio conference, would you like to join."
If user say yes, they would be able to hear and talk to each other.

Our only constraint is to never leave our website.

Could this be done with Twilio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all part of Twilio, but I'm doing something similar in a project and I would say yes, Twilio is a good choice. Although, Twilio is the only company that I've tried, because my client asked specifically to use it.

See here: https://www.twilio.com/webrtc

Just have in mind, that maybe Twilio is not the cheapest option.